# How to use multiple rvm gemsets in single tmuxinator session

Tags: rvm, tmux, tmuxinator

I have a tmuxinator session set up where one tab (editor) is using a project with it's own rvm gemset (and .rvmrc) and another tab (rails) is using a separate rvm gemset (and .rvmrc)

```
project_root: .
tabs:
  - editor:
      layout: main-vertical
      panes:
        - vim
        - # 
  - rails: cd delivery/rails_app ; rails s
```

This works fine in tmux but when I try it with tmuxinator I get this error in my rails tab:

```
Using: /Users/stevejackson/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0@finances_rails
Could not find builder-3.2.0 in any of the sources
Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.
```

Strangely enough, if I start tmuxinator from my rails project, everything works fine.

Specifying a gemset using the rvm option doesn't seem to help.

Comment: You can set a `pre_window` like this `pre_window: if [[ -f ".ruby-version" ]] &&  [[ -f ".ruby-gemset" ]]; then rvm use $(cat .ruby-version)@$(cat .ruby-gemset); fi`

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
- rails: $HOME/.rvm/bin/rvm in delivery/rails_app do rails s
```

Comment: Same error.  I can run rvm commands (info, current) from this tab, but I can't do anything that would use bundler or gems (bundle install, gem list).

Answer (score 1):

Just in case anyone else finds this question, I ended up swapping to teamocil and it works as I hoped - only disadvantage is you have to start tmux before jumping into your session.

```
session:
  name: "my_session"
  windows:
    - name: "editor"
      root: "."
      layout: main-vertical
      panes:
        - cmd: "vim"
          focus: true
        - cmd: "pwd"
        - cmd: "guard"
    - name: "rails"
      root: "./delivery/rails_app"
      panes:
        - cmd: "RAILS_ENV=test shotgun"
```